# Is there another way to give id or class name when using CSS Module in React?

Tags: css, module, curly-braces, classname

Whenever I import "style.module.css" then I have to give each component a class name like this: **classname={styles.className}**

Code Example:

```html
import styles from './Header.module.scss'

const Header = () => {
    return(
        <div className={styles.Container}>
            <h1 className={styles.PageTitle}>This is Header</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Is there a more convenient way than typing the **classname={styles.className}** ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this be more handy?

```js
import styles from './styles.module.css';

const {
  'block__element': blockOneClass,
  'bock__element--modifier': otherClass,
  footer: footerClass,
  // ...
} = styles;

const element = <div className="{blockOneClass}"></div>;
```